# The initialization of the dynamically allocated memory in C

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I am still confused with the two functions malloc() and calloc()
As we know calloc() initialize the memory it allocates while malloc() doesn't.
But when I tried the following code, the result seemed unexpected.

```
typedef struct{
    int *val;
}Node;
int main()
{
    Node *q=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(q->val==NULL) printf("malloc initialized memory\n");
    Node *p=(Node*)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    if(p->val==NULL) printf("calloc initialized memory\n");
}
```

The variables 'val' of val of p and q are both NULL. Isn't q->val uninitialized?
Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Answer (score 1):

The [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function does *not* initialize the memory it allocates. The contents will be *indeterminate* (and might seem "random" or "garbage").

If you want to zero-initialize the memory (which means that all pointers are `NULL`) then use [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), or explicitly initialize the data.

Also note that in C you [should not cast the return of `malloc` (and siblings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/).

Comment: Should I cast the return of calloc() or realloc() then?? If I should, why??

Comment: @Liu No, that's what I meant by "siblings". In C you shouldn't cast the result of *any* function returning `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is uninitialized, formally it means that its value is **indeterminate**.  It could be any value, and 0 is just as random as any other value.  Just because you read 0 doesn't necessarily mean the variable was initialized.

You're actually invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by attempting to read `q->val` because 1) it was not initialized and 2) its address was never taken.  Had its address been taken first you would not have undefined behavior unless the indeterminate value was a trap representation.

Comment: Should I cast the return of calloc() or realloc() then?? If I should, why??

Comment: @Liu [You should not cast the return value of `malloc` or `calloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

The memory chunk returned via `malloc()`, contains indeterminate value. Attempt to use that value may incur unspecified result, as nothing about the value can be guranteed.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.22.3.4/P2

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

Comment: What Sourav is trying to say, I think, is that you can't trust your test to tell you definitively whether the memory was initialized or not. The bytes you're looking at might have been zero already.